# Logging Database Changes

Tags: database, database-design

What is the proper way of storing a changelog, similar to git, for data in a database.

[image: Red lines are removed, green lines are added, dark green text are changes inside a line.]

Currently, I have it set up so that every line in a table is given a unique string id that is used to determine where an edit occurs. When a user wants to change the value in column `juice` from Apple to Orange, it logs the date, time, row id, column name, column initial value, column requested value, and some user information.

The request log looks something similar to this:

> [Timestamp] [Username] [RowID] [Column] [CurrentValue] [RequestValue] [Reason] [Reviewed]

And the values look something like this:

> [2016-04-27 12:00:00] [Jack] [JPMmaaevz] [juice] [Apple] [Orange] [I like oranges more] [false]

You can understand this feels a little messy. Is there a better way of handling change requests in a database?

Comment: If you're looking to keep an entire history of data *changes* then maybe Event Sourcing is what you want.  It's a pretty big investment, though.

Comment: Have you taken a look at couchdb changes feed?

Comment: CouchDB does look interesting, but I prefer something SQL-based. It'd take a good bit of rewriting to switch now.

Comment: The first question to ask is how how you plan to *use* the auditing and how much of it you need. There's a huge difference between replay/undo functionality versus "I need to know who to blame for legal reasons" functionality.

Comment: P.S.: Actually, are you trying to log *operational* changes (like for a customer's name or blog-post edit) or are you trying to log *development* changes (like with configuration data soft-coded into a table)? I just realized that your first example--of a code-change--implies that you're trying to track why table-data was changed during development.

Comment: A normal user has the ability to create new rows in the table, but not edit the existing ones. If they make a typo and don't catch it until after they have created their new line, they create a request like shown above which then gets approved by someone who has edit permissions. The higher permission users like to see bright colors in an easy-to-understand image of some sort to show the change that will be made.

Comment: OK, so it sounds like you're developing a *feature* to track pending/approved/denied change-requests against some kind of business-object, rather than a pervasive logging infrastructure for *all* kinds of changes. Does that sound right?

Comment: There is the sql server change tracking feature, but that's SQL server